# white layer background and bleed?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, background, bleed, white

I am preparing a document to send to print. I was asked to add bleed. Is it necessary for a no background document?  The image on the design will not go all the way to the edge.  Or should I add a white background layer and add the bleed to that?

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you didn't confuse this:**

**1)** Did the printer said "Add bleed if you have elements going to the edges"

or

**2)** did he said "Add bleed and make your print-ready at the size of the bleed".

For #1, you do not add bleed or trim marks. For #2, you do add bleed.

It's normal they will mention to add bleed on a printer requirement/specification sheet as a tip. As you said, if the print people didn't see your design, it's possibly just the protocol. If you don't need bleed, don't add it.

Be careful in adding bleed when you don't need it; some printers blindly shrink your layout to fit a non-bleed sheet OR will charge you for a bleed print even if you don't need it. Or worse, they'll print the trim marks and shrink your layout to fit the sheet... Horrible true story scenario that can happen especially with digital printing or online printers.

If possible simply ask the printer. Local printers usually prefer to not have trim marks and bleed when they're not necessary, especially when using digital prints. It's ok if you put them but make sure to mention it.

White is absence of color, and transparent too. So adding a background or not doesn't matter. What's important is really the dimension of your file.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need the bleed for the image, but you probably are asked to have one to align the page to the rest of the designs they are putting on the plate.

So if they asked that yes, do it.

Edited:

I can think of several reasons for the need of bleed on a printer's metodology.

If you do not asign a bleed you could try to align designs next to each other (A) This can imply that any misaligment can be incremental.

If you use bleed (if your design need it or not that is another issue) You have a more controlled output (B)

Your project ill be printed with other projects. This can be business cards, or it is a magazine add. Your design does not need bleed but the rest do. (C)

You have an aditional process, folding, Varnish, etc. (D)

[image]

There are many reasons to work with a bleed. It does not matter if your design needs it or not.

The only case I would not use a bleed is on a leterhead where the paper is exactly the finish size.

Comment: sorry,I do not understand about "have one to align the page to the rest of the design..." The page design has exactly a 0.4 inch margin all around.  The image is positioned inside exactly within that margin.  I can't expand the image outside the margin because it would ruin the design.  There is the image and then below it, the text aligned  with that image. Like everything inside  a column.  So, maybe you can explain me better what you are saying.  Maybe it is clear to you, but I didn't get it.

Comment: the print people haven't seen the design though...so maybe it is just protocol of asking for people sending  documents with colored background and images all the way to the edge.  I would like to know if adding a white layer background is important. I do understand that white is not an ink. Though softwares can read whether it has a background or not.  It will read that white area and show the exact size and not only read within the text and images.

Comment: Answer edited :o)

Comment: -1 (deserves -10) You're wrong with the "but you probably are asked to have one to align the page to the rest of the designs they are putting on the plate.", just confusing the OP with Prep imposition work that OP shouldn't even care about. What are you talking about anyway, you seem to mix some basic prepress techniques with folding/binding. The answer is NO the OP doesn't need to add bleed UNLESS a template was provided with the bleed. In any case, it's going to be a white area. Printer prefer NO bleed and no trim marks when there's none, plus OP could be charged more because of confusion.

Comment: @Sandc White = absence of color. Transparent = absence of color. You can add a white background or not. It's all considered 0% color anyway and doesn't matter at all!

Comment: @Sandc, Are you more confused with my answer? Or that gives you a clue of some reasons why someone can use the bleed space in diferent scenarios?

Comment: @Rafael It's the printer's job to calculate gripper,  do the imposition for plates, to decide if he wants white bleed or not on his imposition, to calculate the "creep" (what you call "incremental..." which doesn't matter in this case, bleed or not), etc. All stuff the OP doesn't even need to know for this question unless the OP works in a print shop as prepress designer or prep technician or pressman. It might look like extra info to a beginner unfortunately, but the info is misleading and has nothing to do with the OP's question. You forgot to mention the cost factor as well & type of print

Comment: @Rafael The increment of the "no bleed" is barely visible as well & more related to using borders around design in a smart way. Bleed or not if the paper is not well trimmed, the stacks of sheets will have slightly different "borders". Paper is trimmed in many stacks then trimmed again to equalize. And this is a white background. It's more an issue on cheap digital printing because they don't even print straight and always have a 1-2 degree sheet rotation. Not really a big issue on offset commercial printing.